# From many Attribute, I need to get one of them and print in xml String using jaxb

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, marshalling

How to get an **one attribute** alone in Xml String using JAXB from the below class :

for example :

```
public class Student {
    private Integer age;
    private String name;
    private Integer id;

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Expected output in XMLString is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<student_list>
        <id = “1234”/>
        <id = “4567”/>
</student_list>
```

I need the xml String in the same format which i represented above.

Comment: `<id = “1234”/>` is not valid. It should be `<student id="1234">` or `<id>1234</id>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option #1 - `@XmlTransient`

You can map the properties you do not whish to appear in the XML with `@XmlTransient`.

```
public class Student {
    private Integer age;
    private String name;
    private Integer id;

    @XmlTransient
    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @XmlTrasient
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

@XmlAttribute
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

### Option #2 - `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)`

Alternatively you can annotate your class with `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` so that only annotated properties are included in the XML.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Student {
    private Integer age;
    private String name;
    private Integer id;

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using JAXB... you need to generate xsd for your xml output. Then you can generate JAXB binding class from XSD. See example below. Then you use JAXB marshaling/unmarshaling to get beans from xml and vice versa. There is an example: http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

**Output example:**

```
<student_list>
    <student id="123">
        <age>25</age>
        <name>Hello Pelo</name>
    </student>
    <student id="124">
        <age>26</age>
        <name>Hello Selo</name>
    </student>
</student_list>
```

**student.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="student_list" type="student_listType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="student_listType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="studentType" name="student"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="studentType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="age"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="id"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**StudentListType.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "student_listType", propOrder = {
    "student"
})
public class StudentListType {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected StudentType student;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the student property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link StudentType }
     *     
     */
    public StudentType getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the student property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link StudentType }
     *     
     */
    public void setStudent(StudentType value) {
        this.student = value;
    }

}
```

**StudentType.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "studentType", propOrder = {
    "age",
    "name"
})
public class StudentType {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String age;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String name;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String id;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the age property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the age property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setAge(String value) {
        this.age = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the name property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the name property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the id property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the id property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setId(String value) {
        this.id = value;
    }

}
```